# C# doesnt pass foreach code

Tags: c#

The code below read a text file with a header of a path and followed by a list of file names.
the code adds each file (from the second line and on) to a ListView.
For some reason the last two lines are never reached.
Any ideas?

```
    private void loadFromFile()
    {
        if ((faxInOn != null) && File.Exists(@"D:\Settings.ye"))
        {
            string[] s;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Settings.ye", Encoding.Default);
            s = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            faxInOn.changePath(s[0]);
            foreach (string temp in s)
                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
                    if (lvi.Text == temp.Substring(1))
                        lvi.ImageIndex = int.Parse(temp.Substring(0, 1));
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: what last 2 lines? the closing braces? the sr.Close() and sr.Dispose()???

Comment: What do you mean by "the last two lines"? The last two lines of the code, or the last two lines of the text file? Additionally, consider using `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadLines`, which are simpler ways of getting the lines from a file. If you *do* want to use `StreamReader`, use a `using` statement.

Comment: Brackets are your friends. Even if you only have a single statement adding brackets makes your program flow **a lot** clearer.

Comment: Did you debug through?

Comment: The last two code lines
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();

Comment: Are you getting an exception raised? I *think* the code is OK so that's the most likely reason those two lines aren't being executed.

Comment: No exception. just never reached.

Comment: @user1689604 How do you know they are not reached? They have no visible effect. Did you set a breakpoint and are you not seeing the debugger stop, or did you determine this some other way?

Comment: @user1689604 And the rest of the code does get executed, and breakpoints in the rest of the code do cause the debugger to stop? (I've had enough trouble with breakpoints being unreliable in some specific situations that I'm asking to make sure.)

Comment: I didnt see any exception, i got breakpoints that dont really break my code.
I honestly dont know what went wrong there but the solution Phil gave worked good, no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd383503.aspx)

For example:

```
// Read all lines in file, skipping the first header line
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\Settings.ye").Skip(1))
{
   // add to list view
}
```

Comment: You should really put that in a try-catch block.  That could certainly throw a few exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

The way the foreach blocks are used are really inefficient for what I think you are trying to do.  Also, it would be much easier and cleaner for you to use the "using(...)" block so your resources are properly cleaned up and handled correctly.  Please see:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I'll try "for" instead of "foreach", maybe that'll be the answer.
wrapped the code with using, thanks. update:No luck with the "for" instead of "foreach".

Comment: I think the foreach is OK to use how you have but it is inefficient.  That would be O(n^2) performance.  Honestly though since I assume these lists are small, it probably won't be a big deal.  I think what ChrisF above said is true.  You are probably getting an exception but the using should handle it for you.